# How do I subtract inside of an IN clause in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I inherited a ASP application that I'm moving to a PHP codebase.

One query that I'm struggling with is as follows

```
select *
from (
    select TERM_REPORTING,
        LEVEL_GROUPING_DESC,
        New_primary_college_Desc,
        ID_count
    from Enrollment
    ) a
pivot(sum(ID_count) for TERM_REPORTING in (
    [" & 201609 - 400 & "], 
    [" & 201609 - 300 & "],
    [" & 201609 - 200 & "],
    [" & 201609 - 100 & "],
    [" & 201609 & "]
    )
) as total_credit
```

I'm not sure how they were using this & 201609 - 400 & syntax to do math operations inside of the IN statement. How can I get the same result, a list of the past 5 terms, inside of the IN statement purely with Microsoft SQL.

I don't simply want the years. That's not the answer to this question. I want to know how to do this subtraction in the IN statement.

Comment: Remove quotes and & characters and that's it

Comment: I tried changing it to ...TERM_REPORTING in ([201609 - 100]))... but am receiving "The incorrect value "201609 - 100" is supplied in the PIVOT operator."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like they where building some dynamic SQL

The end result would look like this

```
select *
from (
    select TERM_REPORTING,
        LEVEL_GROUPING_DESC,
        New_primary_college_Desc,
        ID_count
    from Enrollment
    ) a
pivot(sum(ID_count) for TERM_REPORTING in (
    [201209], 
    [201309],
    [201409],
    [201509],
    [201609]
    )
) as total_credit
```

> **EDIT as Dynamic SQL**

```
Declare @Base int = 21609
Declare @SQL varchar(max)='
select *
from (
    select TERM_REPORTING,
        LEVEL_GROUPING_DESC,
        New_primary_college_Desc,
        ID_count
    from Enrollment
    ) a
pivot(sum(ID_count) for TERM_REPORTING in (
    [' + cast(@Base - 400 as varchar(25)) +'], 
    [' + cast(@Base - 300 as varchar(25)) +'],
    [' + cast(@Base - 200 as varchar(25)) +'],
    [' + cast(@Base  - 100 as varchar(25)) +'],
    [' + cast(@Base as varchar(25)) +']
    )
) as total_credit
'
Exec(@SQL)
```

Comment: Sorry, If it wasn't clear, I wanted to maintain that dynamic SQL. I want to replace 201609 with the :term variable and have it remain dynamic.